# How to create change set for CloudFormation Template with Transform AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

CloudFormation is failing to create a change set with status reason `Template parameters modified by transform`. This appears to be in reference to the `AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen` transform applied to my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Stack
Transform:
  - 'AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen'

# DEPLOYMENT HOOK
Hooks:
  CodeDeployBlueGreenHook:
  ...
```

This template contains all the resources required to run my application, including an ECS service with a task set which uses Blue/Green deployment when the Task Definition it references is updated, as per [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html). It is my understanding that I want and need to use a change set to update the Task Definition which will then trigger the Blue/Green deployment. However, I can't seem to create the change set in the first place.

Additionally, my template doesn't have any input parameters.

The template is being pulled from S3, after it was zipped and uploaded to the bucket. That template worked just fine for creating the stack, but now that the stack is stable I want to be amending it, not tearing it down and putting a new one up.

Comment: similar discussion here as well: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/37

Comment: Cheers @PatMyron, sadly no answers there. I've left a comment in the hopes that I can get some guidance.

Comment: The BG in CFN is very, very limited with a number of [restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html#blue-green-considerations). Are you sure that  your changes do not violate any of them?

Comment: "Parameters that use dynamic references to retrieve their values from external services. For more information, see Using dynamic references to specify template values."

Ah crap, this may well be it. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Marcin unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. I keep re-reading the docs, but I can't see anything pointing me in the right direction. Does creating a change set transform the template in some way?