# CloudFormation create change set fails with 'Template parameters modified by transform'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a change set for my stack, but it keeps failing with status reason `Template parameters modified by transform`.

I have a CodeBuild project which runs the below and then passes the template on if it's valid:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://<TEMPLATE_FILE>
```

I am using the `CodeDeployBlueGreen` transform to allow Blue/Green deployments with ECS, as per [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/blue-green.html).

```
Transform:
  - 'AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen'
```

My template does not contain any input parameters, and I removed any references to `resolve::ssm...`.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's causing this issue, and I cannot find any documentation which points me in the right direction.

The template is as follows:

***Template removed after answer posted for security.***

Comment: Could you include your template? Also, this question is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64579153/how-to-create-change-set-for-cloudformation-template-with-transform-awscodedep, right?

Comment: @PatMyron Yes, it is, though I think I narrowed down the issue so made a more specific question. This one has been edited to include the template.

Comment: weird..when i ran this aws CLIv2, i got:
`
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://cft.yml
{
    "Parameters": []
}
`

Comment: Yeah, I get the same thing too @LostJon 

{
    "Parameters": []
}

Comment: i noticed in their template sample, they define their VPC key as `Vpc`, whereas yours is all uppercase? just a guess tho...not sure if they have internal requirements based on key casing

Comment: @LostJon That's just a logical ID, basically a variable name. Ought to have no affect whatsoever. Cheers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this saves someone some headaches one day.

This is currently a known issue with CloudFormation in which you *need* to provide the VPC and Subnets as parameters to the stack when using `AWS::CodeDeployBlueGreen` Transform.

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
```

Comment: Do they have to follow this exact naming convention?  I am supplying a VPC parameter and two subnet parameters to my stack, but under different names.  Is that an issue, or should CloudFormation be able to figure it out based on their types?

Answer (score 0):

Probably unrelated, but [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) calls out a missing required property:

[image: Visual Studio Code screenshot]

`[cfn-lint] E3003: Property GroupDescription missing at Resources/NeptuneSG/Properties`

[`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup.GroupDescription`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#cfn-ec2-securitygroup-groupdescription)

Comment: Ah, yeah, `GroupDescription` is actually in my template, I just removed it when I posted here for security. Thanks though.

Comment: @TomBarden gotcha, should look into the [`UpdateReplacePolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html) warnings though :)

Comment: I certainly will! This is not a final version of this template, there's lots to clean up still. I've just hit this roadbump.